# JSP throwing an exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

JSP Page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="loginandsignup/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="loginandsignup/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="form">

        <ul class="tab-group">
            <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="signup">
                <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>

                <c:url var="userRegistration" value="saveUser.html"/>
                <form1:form id="registerForm" modelAttribute="user" method="post" action="${userRegistration}">

                    <div class="top-row">
                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <form1:label path="lastName"> First Name<span
                                    class="req">*</span>
                            </form1:label>
                            <form1:input path="lastName" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <form1:label path="lastName"> Last Name<span
                                    class="req">*</span>
                            </form1:label>
                            <form1:input path="lastName1" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <form1:label path="lastName"> Email Address<span
                                class="req">*</span>
                        </form1:label>
                        <form1:input path="lastName2" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <form1:label path="lastName"> Set A Password<span
                                class="req">*</span>
                        </form1:label>
                        <form1:input path="lastName3" />
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="button button-block">Get
                        Started</button>

                    </form1:form>
            </div>
```

I am getting exception while running above JSP Page

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Spring-hibernate-integration-helloworld] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:76)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form1_005fform_005f0(index_jsp.java:206)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
```

But when I am running the same jsp (Below JSP)  with different format then working fine..

> Different format means in above JSP I have designed JSP page using DIV
>   and below JSP page designed using  html tag.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Being Java Guys | Registration Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div style="color: teal;font-size: 30px">Being Java Guys | Registration Form</div>
<br><br>
<c:url var="userRegistration" value="saveUser.html"/>
<form:form id="registerForm" modelAttribute="user" method="post" action="${userRegistration}">
<table width="400px" height="150px">
<tr>
<td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
<td><form:input  path="firstName"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
<td><form:input  path="lastName"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="gender">Gender</form:label></td>
<td><form:radiobuttons path="gender" items="${model.gender}"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="city">City</form:label></td>
<td><form:select path="city" items="${model.city}"></form:select></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td>
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</td></tr>
</table>
</form:form>
<br>
<a href="userList.html" >Click Here to see User List</a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting idea why I am getting above exception while running the above JSP.  Someone please help me.

I am running the JSP in Tomcate, Spring, Hibernate

Comment: What do you mean by different format, Could you elaborate?

Comment: Please check my update question

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thats a bit strange.. However you can look into [spring.form.tld](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html) which contains all tags with their rendering information. Might help you figure out what is going wrong.

Also check below lines in generated servlet for index.jsp

```
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form1_005fform_005f0(index_jsp.java:206)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:126)
```

You can get generated class in tomcat at below path

```
{TOMCAT_HOME}/work/Catalina/localhost/{app_name}/org/apache/jsp/
```